# Call a PL/pgSQL function with NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, postgresql, plpgsql, jdbctemplate

i have a PL/pgSQL function with following function head:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_workflow_archive(VARCHAR(6),BYTEA[]) RETURNS SETOF TEXT
```

The function was tested successfully.
So i want to call the function with the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate of the spring framework. My java code is following:

```
    String mId; List<byte[]> datas; // Has a valid value
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM create_workflow_archive(:mid, ARRAY[:datas])";
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate createArchive = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(this.dataSource);
    MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    parameters.addValue("mid", mId, Types.VARCHAR);
    parameters.addValue("datas", datas);
    return createArchive.query(sql, parameters, new RowMapper<UUID>() {
        public UUID mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
            return UUID.fromString(resultSet.getString("data"));
        }
    });
```

but I received the exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No value supplied for the SQL parameter 'datas]': No value registered for key 'datas]'
```

How is the right syntax for the JdbcTemplate call of a PL/pgSQL function?

Comment: `BYTEA[]`?? an *array* of blobs? Are you sure you want to pass **multiple** BLOB values into that function? Each one potentially 2GB in size?

Comment: Yes, the BLOB is an encrypted string, so the datas are not very big.

Answer (score 0):

Use keyword **VARIADIC** in the function definition for array parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_workflow_archive(VARCHAR(6), VARIADIC BYTEA[]) RETURNS SETOF TEXT
```

The sql statement changes as:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM create_workflow_archive(:mid, :datas)";
```

Reference:
https://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/211-Variadic-Functions-in-PostgreSQL.html